# Can't download updates for reinstalled Office 2000 on WinXP OS "expected version not found" error message

Tags: microsoft-office, updates

I replaced HD and reinstalled WinXP Pro and successfully downloaded all of the service packs and security updates. I've reinstalled my licensed version of Office 2000 (upgrade version from Office 97). The software installs and is functional; but when trying to install updates SR-1 or SR-1a or any individual security update I get error message "expected version of product not found". Microsoft no longer provides support for this legacy version of office. I can't find any support documents in Microsoft's database that addresses this issue. This is my sister's computer and I've already come out-of-pocket $100 for hardware (not counting the $$hours of labor). She only uses MS Word for minimal correspondence. No desire to spend $100+ for new version of Office.
I would greatly appreciate any suggested fixes for this problem.

Comment: It sounds like it's looking for a dependency from Office 97 that would have stuck around during the upgrade to 2000. Worth a shot to remove everything, reinstall from 97, upgrade it to 2000, and then run the updates.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not getting paid for this and it's a family member, why worry about updating that ancient version of Office?  Just leave it... she should be fine.

If you have to update it for some reason though, you can download it here: 
http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=af6c8d03-7633-45b4-ab96-795ee656f2a2&displaylang=en

Comment: I think the issue is that the update won't install, not that he can't get to it.